# c# how to call interface method in one class from another class?

Tags: c#, interface

I create a class library, and I want to call a method (for example `Form1.SuccessfullActivation()`) from `LicenceManager`, so my question is:

1. Is it possible to do this with interfaces?
2. If yes how can I do this?
3. If no what is the best way for it?

In the class library I have methods for registering and/or validating the product registration, and I want to call methods outside this dll for examle `EnableOrDisableFeatures` is called first with `false` value and it's intended for disabling controlls in a form; or `FailedActivation` is inteded for close the application and alert the user. This is why I need to call the methods from the dll. And I emphasize that the class directory is a stand-alone project, which will be embedded into other projects, so I can't call methods like `Form1.SuccessfullActivation()`.

### Code

**Class library**

```
public interface ILicenceManager
{
    void EnableOrDisableFeatures(bool state);
    void SuccessfullActivation();
    void FailedActivation();
}
public class LicenceManager
{
    public LicenceManager()
    {
        //Call (for example) SuccessfullActivation() from here
    }
}
```

**The project where this dll is embeded**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, ILicenceManager
{
     public Form1()
     {
         new LicenceManager();
     }
    public void EnableOrDisableFeatures(bool state)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SuccessfullActivation()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void FailedActivation()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt a **form** should implement some `ILicenseManager`. In particular as you already have an instance of `licenseManager` in your form-class which should do the work. In order to do this, `LicenseManager` surely must impement `ILicenseManager`, which it currently does not.

Comment: `LicenseManager` should implement `ILicenseManager` and `Form1` should have a property holding an instance of the `LicenseManager` implementation to call the methods on.

Comment: This is totally bizarre.  You have an interface `ILicenseManager`, and a class `LicenceManager` that *doesn't* implement that interface, but instead `Form1` implements it?

Comment: I´m voting to close this question, because it´s unclear what OP actually wants. The class-structure makes no sense at all.

Comment: I would do it with an event on `ILicenceManager`, e.g. `ILicenceManager.OnSuccessfulActivation`.  But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @dbc Yes i did that, and it works as i expected; but I can't answer my question because it's on hold.

Answer (score 3):

As some of the comments have indicated, I don't think you have your bits hooked up the right way. Here's one way you could go about it:

```
public interface ILicenseManager
{
    ...
}

public class LicenseManager: ILicenseManager
{
    // must implement all ILicenseManager methods
}

public partial class Form1: Form1
{
    private readonly ILicenseManager _licenseManager;

    public Form1()
    {
        _licenseManager = new LicenseManager();
    }        
}
```

Now your form has a reference to a `LicenseManager`, which implements `ILicenseManager`, and you can call methods on that object in your form whenever you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [constructor injection](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177649/what-is-constructor-injection) (a type of Dependency Injection) to get the `LicenceManager` functionality in your form:

```
public interface ILicenceManager
{
    void EnableOrDisableFeatures(bool state);
    void SuccessfullActivation();
    void FailedActivation();
}

public class LicenceManager : ILicenceManager
{
    // insert implementation here
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ILicenceManager _licenceManager;

    // Provide the implementation when calling the constructor e.g.:
    // new Form1(new LicenceManager());
    public Form1(ILicenceManager licenceManager)
    {
        this._licenceManager = licenceManager;
        // now you can make calls on this instance, e.g.
        // this._licenceManager.FailedActivation();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't "constructor injection", as you put it. It's just a constructor with a parameter. Injection happens when you use some sort of inversion-of-control container.

Comment: @Enigmativity That´s not true. Constructor-injection is just to put the dependency via a constuctor instead of letting your class create its own depency. You don´t have to use a DI-container for that. In fact DI makes no statement about *who* resolves the dependencies.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I removed the public methods. If you want to know why the form needs them or when they are called, you should ask OP.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - Thank you - I went and read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection - you are spot on. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: But I want to use this the other way around, I want to call the method from `LicenceManager` and the method is in the `Form1` class.

Comment: "poor man's DI"

Comment: @NoelNemeth that design does not make sense.  Your BL should not depend on the UI, it should be the other way around.

Comment: @NoelNemeth Then it's most likely badly designed. Forms are for UI. Business logic should go somewhere else.

Comment: @rory.ap Indeed.

Comment: @NoelNemeth -- The UI should be as minimal as possible for many reasons, some of which are re-workability of the UI -- makes it easy to upgrade or switch UI technologies; and testability of your complex code.  Take a look at patterns like MVVM and MVC.

Comment: @marsze The main idea for this entire project is: I have a program and I have the `LicenceManager` call library; when I create a new program I include this class library into it; this class library validates the registration, or registers the program; and I want to call for example `EnableOrDisableFeatures` from the dll to execute code in the program that disables the controlls (because the dll isn't know what to disable, and I can't make it constant)